# How to check duplicate data using Realm in Android

Tags: android, database, duplicates, realm, realm-mobile-platform

In my App I have stored some mockdata to show at the starting of the app. Now I have another option to add data into Realm database. But in my app, all the duplicate data is stored within the database. For Example I have three data in setRealmData() method. within this method I created same data with similar information. This data is checked perfectly. But whenever I tried to add a new data with simialer name it also stored within the app, which I do not want actually. How can I duplicate check in with preload data to new data in Realm.

My Activity Class is

```
public class MyColleaguesPage extends AppCompatActivity implements MyColleaguesAdapter.ColleagueListListener{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MyColleaguesAdapter adapter;
private Realm colleagueRealm;
private RealmResults<MyColleagueModel> dataResult;
private static final String DIALOG_TAG = "EmployeeDialog";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mycolleagues_layout);

    // Showing and Enabling clicks on the Home/Up button
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
    colleagueRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.colleagues_recycler);

    setUpRecycler();

    if (!Prefs.with(this).getPreLoad()) {
        setRealmData();
    }
    showAllPersons();
}

private void showAllPersons() {
    dataResult = colleagueRealm.where(MyColleagueModel.class).findAll();
    setAdapter(dataResult);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void setAdapter(RealmResults<MyColleagueModel> results) {

    adapter = new MyColleaguesAdapter(this, colleagueRealm.where(MyColleagueModel.class).findAllSortedAsync("id"),this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
private void setUpRecycler() {
    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    // use a linear layout manager since the cards are vertically scrollable
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}

private void setRealmData(){

    List<MyColleagueModel> colleague = new ArrayList<>();
    MyColleagueModel model = new MyColleagueModel();
    model.setId(1);
    model.setName("Name1");
    model.setCompany("Comapny1");
    model.setTitle("Title1");
    colleague.add(model);
    model = new MyColleagueModel();
    model.setId(2);
    model.setName("Name2");
    model.setCompany("Comapny2");
    model.setTitle("Title1");
    colleague.add(model);
    model = new MyColleagueModel();
    model.setId(2);
    model.setName("Name2");
    model.setCompany("Comapny2");
    model.setTitle("Title1");
    colleague.add(model);
    model = new MyColleagueModel();
    model.setId(3);
    model.setName("Name3");
    model.setCompany("Comapny3");
    model.setTitle("Title3");
    colleague.add(model);


    for (MyColleagueModel realmModel : colleague) {
            // Persist the colleague data
        colleagueRealm.beginTransaction();
        colleagueRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(realmModel);
        colleagueRealm.commitTransaction();
    }

    Prefs.with(this).setPreLoad(true);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.recycler_menu, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    //onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) add will open dialog box, which allows user to fill required data
    if (id == R.id.addColleague) {
        showAlertDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showAlertDialog() {
    EditColleagueFragment dialog = new EditColleagueFragment();
    //dialog.setPositiveButtonClickListener(this);
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TAG);
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (colleagueRealm!= null)
        colleagueRealm.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

My EditDialog Fragment Class is

```
public class EditColleagueFragment extends DialogFragment {
private EditText id;
private EditText name;
private EditText role;
private EditText company;
private EditText mobile;
private EditText email;
private EditText department;

private View view;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Realm mRealm;

/*public interface onSaveClickListener {
    void onSaved();
}
private onSaveClickListener mSaveClickListener;

public void setPositiveButtonClickListener(onSaveClickListener listener){
    mSaveClickListener=listener;
}*/
public EditColleagueFragment() {

}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_my_colleague, null);
    id = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
    name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    role = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.role);
    company = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.company);
    mobile = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile);
    email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.email);
    department= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.department);

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    dialog.setTitle("Add Colleague");
    dialog.setView(view);
    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            savePerson();
        }
    });
    return dialog.create();
}

private void savePerson() {
    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    mRealm.beginTransaction();

    MyColleagueModel model=new MyColleagueModel();
    model.setId(id.getId());
    model.setName(name.getText().toString());
    model.setTitle(role.getText().toString());
    model.setCompany(company.getText().toString());
    model.setMobile(mobile.getText().toString());
    model.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
    model.setDepartment(department.getText().toString());

    mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(model);
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
    mRealm.close();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to avoid duplication of data using the Realm Mobile Platform is to use primary keys.

Normally, all insertions and updates are preserved when synchronizing data between clients, but often multiple clients want to insert data that is logically identical. To ensure that those insertions are collapsed into single objects, you can use a primary key column on the model by which the objects can be identified on both clients. If two clients each insert an object with the same primary key value, the objects will be considered logically the same, and you will end up with just the one object after synchronization.

You haven't shared your model, but it looks like there is an "ID" field — that could serve as the primary key. :-)

Note that if you are only making local changes (no synchronization), primary key conflicts will result in an error being thrown, and you manually have to handle the case of preexisting objects.

If using primary keys is inconvenient for your use case, you always have the option to wait for download to complete and then manually clean up the database — just make sure that clients are able to make the same decisions about which object to discard, so as to avoid throwing away more than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

try use code below

```
   public <E extends RealmModel> boolean isDataExist(Class<E> eClass, int id) {
    E data = colleagueRealm.where(eClass).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    return data != null;
}

private void initData(){
 if(isDataExist(MyColleagueModel.class, id.getText().toString())){
  // data exist
 }else{
  // insert new
 }
```

Comment: @Nguyen where canI declare isDataExist method. In maon activity or edit activity class

Comment: Put in place have Realm